# Why do we need VariableEnvironment to identify the state of an Execution Context in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

In the ECMAScript spec, it is stated that:

A LexicalEnvironment :

> Identifies the Lexical Environment used to resolve identifier references made by code within this execution context.

Also,

> The LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components of an execution context are always Lexical Environments. When an execution context is created ***its LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components initially have the same value.***

And that:

> Usually a Lexical Environment is associated with some specific syntactic structure of ECMAScript code such as a FunctionDeclaration, a BlockStatement, or a Catch clause of a TryStatement and a ***new Lexical Environment is created each time such code is evaluated***.

The question is, why do we need a VariableEnvironment in first place, since the a LexicalEnvironment seems to be enough to track variable-value bindings?

Now, let's have a look at this code example in JavaScript [Questions in comments] :

```js
var a = 1;
function x(b){
    var c = 2;
    // During the creation phase of the excution context of the function 
    // the ifStatement Block will it be skipped? 
    if(c >= 1){
        let d = 3;
        // Does e belongs to the Lexical Environment of the IfStatementBlock or to the FunctionDeclaration?
        var e = 4; 
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*VariableEnvironment* is used for names that are scoped to the entire function, while *LexicalEnvironment* is used for names that are scoped to the closest enclosing block (EcmaScript 6's `let` and `const` declarations).

In your example, `c` and `e` both belong to the *VariableEnvironment* of the function. `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function, but `e` won't be initialized unless the `if` block is entered. So it's equivalent to:

```js
var a = 1;

function x(b) {
  var c = 2;
  var e;
  if (c >= 1) {
    let d = 3;
    e = 4;
    a = 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: The lexical environment of a block includes the lexical environments of containing blocks and the function.

Answer (score 1):

> why do we need a VariableEnvironment in first place, since the a LexcicalEnvironment seems to be enough to track variable-value bindings?

The reason for the VariableEnvironmnet is to ensure that there is a local scope that can be used which does not interfere with the existing scopes. Without a VariableEnvironment, there would be no scoping at all, as the LexicalEnvironment would constantly be altered by executing code.

> **VariableEnvironment** - Identifies the Lexical Environment whose EnvironmentRecord holds bindings created by VariableStatements within this execution context.

This is definitely needed.

> During the creation phase of the excution context of the function, the if Statement Block will it be skipped?

No, it will not. `if` statements are not triggers for new execution contexts, and as a result that scope will be part of the Variable Environment of the function which will hold an inner LexicalEnvironment.

> Does e belongs to the Lexical Environment of the IfStatementBlock or to the FunctionDeclaration?

The `e` variable is hoisted, since it is a `var`, and as such it is part of the Variable Environment for function x. The `d` value is part of an inner LexicalEnvironment created as a result of the `let` declaration inside of an `if` block.